# jbpm6 example application rewards-jsf deployment error

Tags: java, jboss7.x, jbpm, jboss-weld

I am getting below error when deploying rewards-jsf application. Please advise.

```
07:18:41,768 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."rewards-jsf-6.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".WeldService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."rewards-jsf-6.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".WeldService: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001409 Ambiguous dependencies for type [UserGroupCallback] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject private org.jbpm.examples.util.RewardsApplicationScopedProducer.usergroupCallback]. Possible dependencies [[Managed Bean [class org.jbpm.examples.util.RewardsUserGroupCallback] with qualifiers [@Any @Default], Producer Method [UserGroupCallback] with qualifiers [@Any @Default] declared as [[method] @ApplicationScoped @Produces public org.jbpm.kie.services.cdi.producer.DefaultUserGroupInfoProducer.produceCallback()]]]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:83)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001409 Ambiguous dependencies for type [UserGroupCallback] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject private org.jbpm.examples.util.RewardsApplicationScopedProducer.usergroupCallback]. Possible dependencies [[Managed Bean [class org.jbpm.examples.util.RewardsUserGroupCallback] with qualifiers [@Any @Default], Producer Method [UserGroupCallback] with qualifiers [@Any @Default] declared as [[method] @ApplicationScoped @Produces public org.jbpm.kie.services.cdi.producer.DefaultUserGroupInfoProducer.produceCallback()]]]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:278)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:244)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:107)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:127)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:346)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:331)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:366)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldContainer.start(WeldContainer.java:83)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:76)
    ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DefaultUserGroupInfoProducer should already be marked as an alternative, and thus would need to be specified in beans.xml to pick it up, is that the case?  If so, removing it from beans.xml should disable it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue for sure: 
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001409 Ambiguous dependencies for type [UserGroupCallback]:
Injection point where the UserGroupCallBack is required ->   @Inject private org.jbpm.examples.util.RewardsApplicationScopedProducer.usergroupCallback].

1) First possible match: 
[[Managed Bean [class org.jbpm.examples.util.RewardsUserGroupCallback] with qualifiers [@Any @Default],

2) Second Match: Producer Method [UserGroupCallback] with qualifiers [@Any @Default] declared as [[method] @ApplicationScoped @Produces public org.jbpm.kie.services.cdi.producer.DefaultUserGroupInfoProducer.produceCallback()]]]

One of these two must go away in order to work. I guess that RewardsUserGroupCallback is the one intenteded for this application (I don't really know where this application is hosted or the internals of it) so you need to review the code.